# GT table not displaying as expected in R

Tags: r, statistics, visualization, gt

I am using GT table for the first time, and am confused by how it is generating the output.

Code is below. Before passing it through gt() the dataframe produced by the "group_by" function formats the table as expected i.e. 4 headings and 12 rows. After gt() it does somehthing odd to to the 'course' and 'unit' variables, pics below. Any ideas or suggestions for formatting the gt table in the same way the dataframe is constructed?

```
df <- read.table(text=
"Unit Course RR Score
20539 B 0.34 4.500
10526 B 0.10 4.470
10522 C 0.11 4.444
10521 C 0.28 4.424
10460 A 0.27 4.390
20541 B 0.23 4.334
10462 A 0.27 4.204
10456 A 0.35 4.190
10461 A 0.27 4.174
10524 C 0.12 4.084
10527 B 0.09 3.970
10523 C 0.14 3.696", header=TRUE)

library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

final_table <- df %>% 
  group_by(Unit, Course) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = c("RR", "Score"), .funs = ~mean(., na.rm = T)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Score)) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  cols_label(
    RR = ("Response Rate %"), 
    Score = "Mean Score") %>% 
  opt_align_table_header(align = "left") %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = Score) %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = RR, scale_by = 100/1, decimals = F) %>% 
  cols_width(
    Unit ~ px(150),
    RR ~px(150),
    Score ~px(150)) %>% 
  cols_align("center") %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = Score, 
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c(
        "red","orange","green"),
             domain = c(3,3.5,4.0,4.5,5)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbQFn.png)

Removed 'Course' from the "group_by function", but this obviously just leaves it out of the final table which is no good.

the data in the csv looks like this, if it makes a difference?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p16Zp.png)

Comment: Try replacing `gt()` with `gt(row_group_as_column = TRUE)`. (While I like gt, I strongly dislike this default.)

Comment: thanks for the reply - this gave me `Error in gt(., row_group_as_column = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (row_group_as_column = TRUE)` ? I feel the issue is related to how the original `group_by` function is generating the dataframe from the original data?

Comment: What version of gt are you using, because it very much is an argument. See [here](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/gt.html).

Comment: ...and it is definitely not the `group_by()`. I've dealt with this countless times, the vertical placement of row groups is just the default formatting of gt, and is intentional.

Comment: version 0.9.0. It's weird it doesn't appear when I start typing `row_group....` I only get `row_group.sep` and `row_group_order`

Comment: Maybe it's only in the dev version. Try `tab_options(row_group.as_column = NULL)`.

Comment: no error when I use `tab_options(row_group.as_column = NULL)` but it appears to have no effect on the output?

Comment: Well, I'd be happy to give you a concrete solution if you provided a reproducible example.

Comment: My only other thought, without a reproducible example, is that maybe you intended both grouping columns to be retained, but I believe the summarise functions by default strip the outer grouping variable, so the result is only grouped by Unit.

Comment: That would be great - what's the best way to provide a reproducible example? Yes I do agree I think the issue is I want to retain both grouping columns but the summarise function is removing Course.

Comment: If its helpful I've put the csv file and code here https://github.com/JFern83/GT-issue

Comment: I think this has solved it `grouped_df <- aggregate(Score ~ Unit + Course + RR, data = df, FUN = mean) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Score))` before passing to `gt()` retains the course and unit info in the final output, without the weird formatting issue.

Comment: Also, just recalling `group_by(Unit, Course)` just before `gt()` moves both variables into the row group headings, but I think what you're unhappy with is ultimately just how gt formats row groups by design. (I don't like it either.)

Comment: yep exactly that, including `Unit, Course` works but I wanted them all on the same row, so it would be easy to see when ordered on 'Score' if there was a higher frequency of a specific course or not at the top or bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but simply putting `ungroup()` before the `gt()` call makes it return a table with 4 columns and 12 rows, as you requested:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Unit, Course) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = c("RR", "Score"), .funs = ~mean(., na.rm = T)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Score)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% # new line
  gt() %>% 
  cols_label(
    RR = ("Response Rate %"), 
    Score = "Mean Score") %>% 
  opt_align_table_header(align = "left") %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = Score) %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = RR, scale_by = 100/1, decimals = F) %>% 
  cols_width(
    Unit ~ px(150),
    RR ~px(150),
    Score ~px(150)) %>% 
  cols_align("center") %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = Score, 
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c(
        "red","orange","green"),
             domain = c(3,3.5,4.0,4.5,5)))
```

[image: table]

Comment: Yes `ungroup` has done the trick too - I never thought of that, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably are satisfied with your own solution, but this is as close as I can get to what I think you're looking for.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Unit, Course) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = c("RR", "Score"), .funs = ~mean(., na.rm = T)) %>% 
  arrange(Course,desc(Score)) %>%
  select(Course,Unit,RR,Score) %>%
  group_by(Course) %>%
  gt(row_group_as_column = TRUE) %>% 
  tab_stubhead(label = 'Course') %>%
  cols_label(
    RR = ("Response Rate %"), 
    Score = "Mean Score") %>% 
  opt_align_table_header(align = "left") %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = Score) %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = RR, scale_by = 100/1, decimals = F) %>% 
  cols_width(
    RR ~px(150),
    Score ~px(150)) %>% 
  cols_align("center") %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = Score, 
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c(
        "red","orange","green"),
             domain = c(3,3.5,4.0,4.5,5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a different but very useful way to display this information!